# Any open source alerting and reporting plugin for ELK stack is available?

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins, logstash, kibana

I'm using Logstash, Elasticsearch and kibana 5.5.2 . I want an email alerting and reporting feature for ELK stack. Is there any open source tool for this features?

Comment: A few options are listed here: https://sematext.com/blog/x-pack-alternatives/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have installed sentinl and using it but getting error like connection encountered an error, while sending mail.  What will be the host for outlook mail to write in .yaml file so that I can resolve the error.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you need this:[GitHub - Yelp/elastalert: Easy & Flexible Alerting With ElasticSearch](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert)

Comment: Thanks for the help.Actually already referred it but of no use.

Comment: Update: grafana supports elasticsearch data source from version 5.x and you can use grafana alerting functions.http://docs.grafana.org/features/datasources/elasticsearch/